# How can I make my GridView items rearrangeable(drag and drop)?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a GridView with a custom adapter and item layout. I want the user to be able to hold one of the items to move it into another item's place, just like moving icons on the homescreen.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Or is there a different way I should go about this?

Comment: first see this :-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: After that you can do tricks with your custom adapter like swapping the items in the list of the `adapter`